# Translation of "Normale im Wendepunkt"

Tags: calculus, translation-request, mathematical-german

Please, can you help me to translate into English and solve this exercise:

> Der Term von $f$ wird variiert: $f_{a}(x)=ax(x-3)^{2}$. Bestimme $a$ so dass die Normale im Wendepunkt durch den Punkt $(0|0)$ geht.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Translation:**

For the function $f_a(x)=ax(x-3)^2$ determine $a$ such that the normal at the [point of inflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) passes through the point $(0,0)$.

**Solution summary:**

The point of inflection can be found by finding $x_a$ such that $f_a''(x_a)=0$; the point of inflection is then clearly $(x_a,f_a(x_a))$ . As the tangent has slope $ f_a'(x_a)$, the normal has slope $-\frac1{f_a'(x_a)}$. Combine these results to find $a$.

**Detailed solution:**

By the product rule, the first derivative is: $$f_a'(x)=a(x-3)^2+2ax(x-3)=3a(x-1)(x-3)$$ the second derivative is: $$f_a''(x)=3a(x-3)+3a(x-1)=6a(x-2)$$ and 
$f_a'''(x)=6\,a$, for later reference.

The case $a=0$ is special: If $a=0$, then $f_a(x)=0$, the function graph has no point of inflection there and so has no solution. (At any rate, there is no *"the"* point of inflection).

Hence we assume $a\ne 0$: Then the only possibility for a point of inflection is at $x_a=2$ because $f_a''(x_a)=0\iff x_a=2$.

Since $f_a'''(x_a)=6a\ne0$, the point $(x_a,f_a(x_a))=(2,2a)$ is indeed a point of inflection. The slope of the normal through that point is $$-\frac1{fa'(x_a)}=-\frac1{-3a}=\frac1{3a}.$$ On the other hand, the slope of the line through $(0,0)$ and $(2,2a)$ is $a$.

These slopes (and hence the normal and the line through the origin) coincide iff $a=\frac1{3a}$, i.e. $$a=\pm\frac{\sqrt 3}{3}.$$

Comment: what means point of inflection?

Comment: experiment with [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+8x%28x%E2%88%923%29%5E2 ]

Comment: @Iuli A point of inflection is a point where the function changes from concave to convex or vice versa.

Comment: @Iuli If you drive your car along the graph, your steering wheel passes through the straight position at that moment (going from left to right or from right to left).

Comment: @Iuli: Point of inflection = WendePunkt.